# FASM - Boot sector on USB don't work

Tags: usb, boot, fasm, sector

in first, sorry for my bad english, i'm french.
At the moment, i learn asm with fasm to test boot sector programming.

I have make a simple boot program, i have compiled it and i write boot.bin in first sector of my usb.

But when i boot on my PC or in virtualbox, drive isn't found....

**Boot sector code:**

```
;=======================================================================
;   a simpliest 1.44 bootable image by shoorick ;)
;=======================================================================
_bs equ 512
_st equ 18
_hd equ 2
_tr equ 80
;=======================================================================
    org 7C00h
    jmp start
    nop
;=====================================================
    db  "HE-HE OS";     ; 8
    dw  _bs             ; b/s
    db  1               ; s/c  
    dw  1               ; rs
    db  2               ; fats
    dw  224             ; rde
    dw  2880            ; as 
    db  0F0h            ; media
    dw  9               ; s/fat
    dw  _st             ; s/t
    dw  _hd             ; h
    dd  0               ; hs
    dd  0               ; --
    db  0               ; drv
    db  0               ; --
    db  29h             ; ebr
    dd  0               ; sn
    db  "NO NAME    ";  ; 11
    db  "FAT12   ";     ; 8
;=====================================================
start:
    mov   ax,cs
    mov   ds,ax
    mov   cx,count
    mov   si,hello
    mov   bx,7
    mov   ah,0Eh
@@:
    lodsb
    int   10h
    loop  @B
    xor   ah,ah
    int   16h
    int   19h

hello   db "Hi! This is disk-invalid!"
count = $ - hello  

;=======================================================================
    rb 7E00h-2-$
    db 055h,0AAh
;=======================================================================
```

This code is provide by examples of fasm's website.

Comment: Did you set the correct _boot order_ in your BIOS? If at all possible, move the USB device to the top.

Answer (score 0):

there are couple of reasons why a bootloader wont work:

1. the bootloader is not in the first sector of the USB/Floppy/etc.
2. the bootloader is not **EXACTLY** 512 bytes long
3. you are missing the 0xAA55 signature at the last 2 bytes of the bootloader

in your example i assume you have the wrong bootloader size ( it is not 512 bytes )

try replacing

```
rb 7E00h-2-$
db 055h,0AAh
```

with

```
TIMES 510-($-$$) DB 0
DW 0xAA55
```

this ensures that your file is exactly 512 bytes long and that is has the required bootloader signature

Comment: His assembler file is correct. The DB and DW your are using are the same thing expressed differently. `rb 7E00h-2-$` is in fact valid and will generate the needed bytes to pad out to 510 where the boot signature is placed. Making it 512. `rb` is a _FASM_ directive to reserve a specified number of bytes.

Comment: @Michael Petch hm strange if i try to use his method to pad the 510 bytes then i get a binary file that is 32256 bytes long. im using flat assembler 1.71.51

Comment: I'd expect you'd get 32256 if you didn't use `org 07c00h`